# Using jQuery and angularjs together in one script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Can I use jQuery and AngularJS together in one script? If i use that way, is there any chance of having performance issues?

Comment: It is called jquery not jquary, and you shouldn't have any performance issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how about using Angular2 + JQuery together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41834089/how-about-using-angular2-jquery-together)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

Angular 1.x already has jqLite available.

If you were to also include jQuery, then yes you could see performance degredation.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Answer (score 0):

I use jquery and angular together for a long time, and no problem comes