# What is earliest version of JQuery should I use in Angularjs 1.6.4?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-1.6, angularjs-injector

I use angularjs 1.6.4 in my project and I cant find any place in documentation what is earliest version of JQuery does it use?Currently, in the project I use JQuery 1.1.0 and I have dependency injection error I guess the error caused by the JQuery and AngularJS versions mismatch.

Comment: Ideally you should *not* use jQuery with Angular.  Angular includes jqLite which contains the subset of jQuery that's still useful when using Angular. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41836718/3412322

Comment: That is a very very old version of jQuery.