# Angular 2: http.get Response to String

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

#### Core Question:

I'd like to get the following response into a string rather than an observable.

```
getFacebookPhoto(uid: string): Observable<any> {
    let results = this.http.get('https://graph.facebook.com/' + uid + '/picture?height=200&redirect=false')
    .map(response => response.json().data.url.)
    return results
}
```

#### Additional Information:

I need to populate a list of available photos for my users to choose from. I'm binding the url's of those photos to the template with interpolation with something like `{{ selectedPic }}`. Ideally, something like, `(click)="selectedPic = gravatarUrl"` would change the value of `selectedPic` to the value of `gravatarUrl`, or any of the variables in my component that have string values of a url.

The issue is that `facebookPhoto` is an observable. I'd like to store the emission as a string.

#### Update:

This achieved the goal of storing the emission in the string type variable `selectedPic`:

```
this.memberCreationService.getFacebookPicUrl(uid)
.subscribe(picUrl => this.selectedPic = picUrl)
```

Is there a way to do this without creating a subscription, however? Something that gets the emission and disposes of the observable maybe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular2's Http from '@angular/http'.
http.get will always return an Observable object, you can see it in the function's signature:

```
get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>;
```

This is because this function runs asynchronously, if when you want to fetch data from a server it will have to wait, so it can't just return the string/json object you requested right away.

You should subscribe to the observable after the function call by using the `.subscribe` function it returns, or use `.toPromise()` if you imported the `'rxjs/operator/add/toPromise'` module

ex:

```
getFacebookPhoto("abcd123").subscribe(response => {
    this.myObject = response.json();
}
```

I'd suggest you read about Observables or Promises [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-http-requests-with-observables).

Also, you don't need to use {{}} in here: `(click)="{{selectedPic = gravatarUrl}}"`

Comment: Thanks for the responses, guys. I do understand that I have to subscribe to the observable. What I'm asking, is what is the best way to operate on the observable to get the targeted emission into a string. Also, the curly brackets in the template statement was a mistake.

Comment: That's why I included a second code block that you can see how to use the function you defined.

Comment: Your function signature was `getFacebookPhoto(uid: string): Observable<any>`
To use it you can subscribe to it where you need and pass the response.json() to it.

Comment: Oh, ok. I did something similar in my question already. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295207/how-to-synchronise-angular2-http-get

Comment: That's actually good to know. I guess I was hoping for a way to have the method in the service return the string. Not a good idea apparently.

Comment: Just to be a bit more correct, there is an option to achive what you requested, using the ES2017 feature called [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
You can scroll down and see that it is not widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're subscribing to the event, and the data literally isn't present until it reaches the application.

The Http module is making an async web request to fetch data, so you need to subscribe to be informed when the data is present (and take some action, such as assign the data to a variable.

The subscription is necessary.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Please see the comment on Omri Luzon's answer.