# make http post synch using Observable in Angular

Tags: angular, http, post, observable, synchronous

I'm trying to implement this but need some help (I'm new to this).

I currently have,

```
constructor(http: HttpClient, private cvservice: CvService) {
const req = http.post<any>('url', [{
            "name": "ids",
            "license": "GPL version 2"
}])
  .subscribe(
    res => {
    console.log(res);
    var resp = res.Results[0].results.map(x => {
            return {cvid: x.ID, severity: x.CVSS };
    } );
   this.data = [...resp];
    },
    err => {
      console.log("Error occured");
    }
  );
}
```

This works fine except I need to make the http.post synch (need Results[0] before continuing) and I'm using the suggestion from, [How to synchronise Angular2 http get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295207/how-to-synchronise-angular2-http-get).

I've modified the service as,

```
export class CvService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}
url = 'foo';
getIds():Observable<any[]> {
const url='xxx';
return this.http.post(url, [{
            "name": "ids",
            "license": "GNU General Public License GPL version 2"
        }])
        .map(
            res =>  {
                res.Results[0].results.map( x => {
                   return {cvd: x.ID, severity: x.CVSS };
}));
}
}
}
```

But I think this syntax is wrong. This gives compile error. Can someone please clarify the correct way to use the map function here?

Comment: What version of rxjs are you using? (Bear in mind, as the post you linked to points out, this does not make it sync, **but you shouldn't want it to be sync**. You can work with the async nature of the HTTP calls)

Comment: I think you are using rxjs 6+ and for that you need to use pipe operator `.pipe(map(....))` and if want to chain operators use `,` i.e. `.pipe(map(...), tap(...), ...)`

Comment: Yes; I'm using rxjs 6+. I've implemented this using .pipe(map(..)) but now I need to chain multiple http requests in a specific order. I have to parse the output of one to pass as input data to the next. Is there an example for this?

Answer (score 0):

import map from rxjs and use it inside the pipe like this

```
return this.http.post(URL, Object)
 .pipe(map(data) => {
    return data['result'].map(res => {
   // Here You can return the entire res, or just the properties you want
   // EX: --> return res OR --> return res.cvd
   });
});
```

also, make the object outside

```
let cv = [{
  name: "ids",
  license: "GNU General Public License GPL version 2"
}];
```

You can use it then like this

```
return this.http.post(URL, cv);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this way:

**Service**

```
saveUser(): Observable<any> {
    const data = [{"name": "ids", "license": "GNU General Public License GPL version 2"}];

    // For Angular v5 below
    this.http
      .post(url, data)
      .map(res => res.json());       // or .map(res => res), depends what your fetching with

    OR you can pipe it out (Angular 6+)

    this.http
      .post(url, data)
      .pipe(map(({ Results }: any) => Results[0].results.map(item => ({cvid: item.ID, severity: item.CVSS }))));

    // Based from you code when you accessed it this way: res.Results[0].results.map( x => {return {cvd: x.ID, severity: x.CVSS };
}
```

**Component**

```
this.userService
   .saveUser()
   .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

---

Had created a Stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng6-http-subscribe) for your reference - This uses different data and mocked POST API for demo purposes only.

Comment: This worked great. A quick follow up. I need to chain a few such requests in a specific order. Should I call these functions in the order in which I want them executed? (saveUser1(), parse output1, saveUser2(), parse output2, ...).

Comment: Yes, when you want to implement it in an orderly manner - you should specify it with the order you wanted your pipe function to execute. Would it be great if it could be (saveUser1(() => parseOutput1), saveUser2(() => parseOutput2)) to have 2 methods only in a pipe instead of 4.

Comment: mind if you'll upvote it ? If every my answer helps you with the original problem you had posted? That would be a great help, thanks :)

Comment: I've tried tp upvote; it doesnt seem count since I dont have enough rep. :(